# Visibility of inner template class

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, clang

The code below

```
class X
{
    template<class>
    class A{};
};

int main()
{
    X::A<int> a;
}
```

[compiles in gcc](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c5763aa877baa462) (gcc 6.1), but [fails in clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f7f00bd5e15aeef3) with an error

> error: 'A' is a private member of 'X'

Is there any subtle thing that makes this code valid? In my opinion, it shouldn't compile, hence probably it is a gcc bug. Does it require a diagnostic though?

Comment: I cannot believe that this issue appeared in 2010 and it's still not fixed in gcc.

Comment: Seems it's not yet fixed, after 6 years: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=41437